# How do I launch VBoxHeadless with a Win7 batch file?

Tags: batch-file, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I am trying to run my Virtual machine in headless form from a batch file.

For some reason, I can't make it work. Any suggestions?

This is how I'm trying to run my Virtual Machine:

```
VBoxManage.exe startvm "DebBox" --type "headless"
```

Comment: What does it mean "can't make it work"? Also, this question might be better suited for [Super User](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons that the program isn't running. For starters, you need to use the `start` command to run a program. Additionally, I can almost guarantee that the path where VBox is installed isn't part of your `%path%` variable, which means that you're going to need to either navigate to that directory first or provide the full path in order to run the executable.

```
pushd "C:\path\to\vbox\installation"
start "" VBoxManage.exe startvm "DebBox" --type "headless"
popd
```